# Morley Rank of the cartesian product

Tags: model-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two definable sets with $RM(X), RM(Y)<\omega$.

Can we say something about $RM(X\times Y)$? If $X$ and $Y$ have Morley Rank $0$, then so does $X\times Y$. I think I can prove that $RM(X\times Y)\geq RM(X) + RM(Y)$.

Does the equality hold? If it does not, does it hold in any special case? (like $Y=X$ or $X=Y=\mathfrak{C})$

Comment: I tried to prove the equality, but my problem lies in the fact that definable subsets of $X\times Y$ might not be of  the form $A\times B$ .

Comment: Hi! Yes, maybe I could use that solution to have a better grasp of the concept of Morley Rank. For the case of the empty set I was thinking that $RM(\emptyset)=-\infty$, then the equality should still hold

Comment: oh you're right, I forgot the convention that $\varnothing$ has Morley rank $-\infty$ :) (for some reason I was remembering it as $-1$)

Comment: I have seen both conventions used, depending on the book

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're correct that $\mathrm{RM}(X\times Y)\geq \mathrm{RM}(X)+\mathrm{RM}(Y)$ in general.

Actually, in the possibly infinite rank case, we get: $\mathrm{RM}(X\times Y) \geq \mathrm{RM}(X) \oplus \mathrm{RM}(Y)$, where $\oplus$ denotes the [natural sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Natural_operations) of ordinals. Natural sum agrees with ordinary sum on finite ordinals, but it is greater than the ordinary sum in general. For example, $1+\omega = \omega$, but $1\oplus \omega = \omega + 1$. So, for example, if $\mathrm{RM}(X) = 1$ and $\mathrm{RM}(Y) = \omega$, then $$\mathrm{RM}(X\times Y) \geq 1\oplus \omega = \omega+1 > \mathrm{RM}(X) + \mathrm{RM}(Y).$$

Ok, but you asked about the finite rank case. Unfortunately, the equality  $\mathrm{RM}(X\times Y) = \mathrm{RM}(X) + \mathrm{RM}(Y)$ is not true in general, but I don't know a simple counterexample. In the paper [Singular properties of Morley rank](https://doi.org/10.4064/fm-108-3-145-157), Lachlan gives an example (on pp. 151-152) of a definable set $X$ with $\mathrm{RM}(X) = 3$ but $\mathrm{RM}(X\times X) = 7$. It is too involved for me to reproduce here. Lachlan also produces upper and lower bounds for how much the Morley rank can grow in products of definable sets.

One fairly clean result is: When $\mathrm{RM}(X) = 0$, $\mathrm{RM}(X\times Y) = \mathrm{RM}(Y)$, and when $\mathrm{RM}(X)>0$, $$\mathrm{RM}(X\times Y) \leq (\mathrm{RM}(X)\cdot \mathrm{RM}(Y)) + \mathrm{RM}(X) = \mathrm{RM}(X)\cdot (\mathrm{RM}(Y)+1).$$ This is  a consequence of Exercise 6.4.4 in Tent and Ziegler's book *A Course in Model Theory*.

Ok, what about situations where the equality does hold? Well, it holds whenever the Morley rank is equal to the [Lascar rank](https://modeltheory.fandom.com/wiki/Lascar_rank) (see also the last section of Lachlan's paper linked above). This is the case in uncountably categorical theories and in groups of finite Morley rank. The additivity of the Lascar rank (made precise by the "Lascar inequalities") is one of the main reasons the Lascar rank is a key tool in stability theory, even when both Lascar rank and Morley rank are defined.

Comment: Very nice answer, thank you very much! I will have a look at the counterexample